# Creating json file inside a specific directory using terminal

Tags: json, node.js, npm, terminal, npm-init

I'm trying to create my Starter Pack Setup and I need to install `NPM` dependencies. I should create a `json` file in: `/Users/matteomattiussi/Documents/Udemy/Bootstrap/bs4projects/bs4starter`
but I don't know how do it because I always getting the json file in:
`/Users/matteomattiussi/package.json`

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What command do you use to create the file?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a `package.json` file in `/Users/matteomattiussi/Documents/Udemy/Bootstrap/bs4projects/bs4starter` (if the directory already exists and you have `npm` installed):

```
cd /Users/matteomattiussi/Documents/Udemy/Bootstrap/bs4projects/bs4starter
npm init
```

In [using package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json):

> This will initiate a command line questionnaire that will conclude
>   with the creation of a package.json in the directory you initiated the
>   command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use online JSON compiler and then download it in your directory.  https://jsoneditoronline.org/
This is a example of a site which can create JSON file online.